# d3 stacked bar chart gets stripes when drawing many bars

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have constructed a stacked bar chart with approx 700 bars. Everything function as it should but I am getting really frustrated with the stripes that appear when the chart is drawn. Below is a screenshot with the default view and a zoomed view.

[zoomed view to the left, default to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc9RW.png)

I suspect that the stripes come from the padding between the bars. I've tampered with the bar width to try and eliminate the padding but the stripes are still there. Currently the bar width code looks like this:

```
.attr("width",((width-(padding+xPadding))/data.length)+0.01)
```

The "+0.01" removes the padding and if I increase it further to, say 1, the stripes are gone. However, now the bars are stacked on each other noticably, which I do not want. I suspect there is some quick fix to this(maybe css or something other trivial) but I cannot find it myself. So, how do I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: 
Tried using scalebands as suggested in comments but it had no effect on the stripes.
[same behaviour with scalebands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGROo.png)

EDIT 2:
Added relevant code used to draw rectangles. Note the code does not run, snippet is just for viewing the code.

```js
d3.csv("vis_temp.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
                        for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length-1; ++i){ //calculate total values. ignore last column(usecase) 
                                t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
                        }
                        d.total = t;
                        return d;
                        }, function(error,data){
                                if(error){
                                        console.log(error);
                                        return;
                                }
                                console.log(data);
                                dataset = data; // save data outside of d3.csv function
                                header = data.columns.slice(1); //prop1, prop2..... no sample
                                header.splice(header.length-1,1); //remove usecase from header
                                stack = d3.stack().keys(header);
                                maxValue = d3.max(data,function(d){
                                        return d.total;});
                                samples = data.map(function(d){
                                                return d.sample;});
                                
                                xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                                        .domain([1,samples.length+1])
                                        .range([padding+1,width-xPadding]);
                        
                        /* using scalebands
                                xScale = d3.scaleBand()
                                        .domain(d3.range(data.length))
                                        .range([padding+1,width-xPadding]);
                        */
                                yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                                        .domain([0,maxValue])
                                        .range([height-padding,padding]);

                                zScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                                        .domain(header)
                                        .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]); // low profile, stylish colors

                                xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
                                        .scale(xScale)
                                        .ticks(nbrOfXTicks);

                                yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
                                        .scale(yScale)
                                        .ticks(nbrOfYTicks);
                                        
                                                                        svg.append("text")
                                        .attr("class","chart_item")
                                        .attr("x",(width-padding-xPadding-20)/2)
                                        .attr("y",padding/2)
                                        .text("measurement");

                                svg.append("text")
                                        .attr("class","chart_item")
                                        .attr("x",padding/3)
                                        .attr("y",height/2)
                                        .attr("transform","rotate(270,"+padding/3+","+height/2+")")
                                        .text("Time [ms]")


                                svg.append("text")
                                        .attr("class","chart_item")
                                        .attr("x",(width-padding-xPadding)/2)
                                        .attr("y",height-7)
                                        .text("Sample");

                                svg.append("g")
                                        .attr("class","axis")
                                        .attr("id","x_axis")
                                        .attr("transform","translate(0,"+(height-padding)+")")
                                        .call(xAxis);

                                svg.append("g")
                                        .attr("class","axis")
                                        .attr("id","y_axis")
                                        .attr("transform","translate("+padding+",0)")
                                        .call(yAxis);

                                svg.append("g").attr("class","data");
svg.select(".data")
                                        .selectAll("g")
                                                .data(stack(data)) 
                                                .enter()
                                                .append("g")
                                                        .attr("class","data_entry")
                                                        .attr("id",function(d){
                                                                return d.key;})
                                                        .attr("fill",function(d){
                                                                return zScale(d.key);})
                                                .selectAll("rect")
                                                        .data(function(d,i){
                                                                return d;})
                                                        .enter()
                                                        .append("rect")
                                                        .attr("id",function(d){
                                                                return "bar_"+d.data.sample;})
                                                        .style("opacity",function(d){
                                                                return d.data.usecase=="E" ? val1 : val2;})//some bars opacity change
                                                        .attr("width",((width-(padding+xPadding))/data.length)+0.01)  // +0.01 to remove whitespace between bars 
                                                        //.attr("width",xScale.bandwidth()) use this with scalebands
                                                        .attr("height",function(d){
                                                                return (yScale(d[0])-(yScale(d[1])));
                                                                })
                                                        .attr("x",function(d){
                                                                return xScale(d.data.sample);})
                                                        .attr("y",function(d){
                                                                return yScale(d[1]);})
                                                        .on("mouseover",mouseover) //tooltip on mouseover
                                                        
                                
                                                        .on("mouseout", function() {
                                                                d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
                                                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

When using ordinal scale for x axis, you can set the bar padding in the range.

For example:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
        .rangeBands([0, width], 'padding');
```

A regular `padding` value would be around 0.1, but you can set to 0 since you don't want padding.

Now, you can set your width attr like this: `.attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())`

Comment: I tried the ordinal scale with rangebands and padding set to 0 but I still get the same behaviour as previously(if not worse). The "stripes" are still there. I add screen shot to original question.

Comment: @AndreasWiberg You need to put your code so we can try to solve this. Since I don't have enough reputation, I couldn't comment to ask you for the code. I'll delete this answer.